# npm run deploy Failed to minify the code from ./node_modules/nanoid/index.browser.js:34

Tags: npm, npm-run

I'm trying to deploy my app-v1 to github
However, receives a series of error messages. The latest:

> Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
    ./node_modules/nanoid/index.browser.js:34
```

line 34 in index.browser.js

`let random = bytes => crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(bytes))`

My questions to you are:

1. can I safely delete line 34?
2. Or should I completely ignore using `nanoid`?

Thank you in advance for your help and time

Greetings
/ Peter

Comment: Please share more details. Of course, you can start removing lines from your application - but I doubt that it would work the same way afterwards

Comment: @Nico Haase: What details are of interest?